# what is the cause of binary xml file line #6 error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-inflate

i'm stuck with binary xml file line #6 error inflating class fragment exception ... i'm using a 3rd party library in creating my view... i need to know when exactly this exception is thrown in general, so i can work around it i have tried to remove my view and re-inflate it but nothing works ..

```
if (rootView != null) {
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
                    if (parent != null) {
                        parent.removeAllViews();
                        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.near_you,
                                container, false);
```

there is my xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/beyondarFragment"
        android:name="com.beyondar.android.fragment.BeyondarFragmentSupport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pin_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/pin_button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You have an error in line 6 of the XML R.layout.near_you

Comment: please post your layout file near_you.xml

Comment: check the edit in my post please

Comment: Are you trying to inflate a fragment on API < 11 without the support library?

Comment: If the inflation is inside a fragment, then you cannot do it that way. Then you have to use something like `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(new BeyondarFragmentSupport()).commit()`

Comment: no i'm using the support library but my class extends fragment ..getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(mBeyondarFragment.getId(), temp)
      .commit();

Comment: @cYrixmorten i've tried it, the same exception

Comment: I suspect your inflater should come from the parent instead of the rootView. I think an issue is that since you removeAllViews, the inflater does not have a valid View or Context anymore. Another, it may be difficult to diagnose this problem since you only have code snippet.